# Any reason not to delete Service Pack Backup Files?

Tags: windows-7, service-pack, disk-cleanup

I am using Windows 7 SP1, and I ran the Disk Cleanup utility.

It tells me that I can save 920MB if I delete the Service Pack Backup Files.

Apparently, if I do so, I won't be able to uninstall the service pack.

Is that a good reason not to delete those files? Is there any reason why I would want to uninstall the service pack?

Comment: You tell us?  If you don't care about not being able to remove the Service Pack then delete the backup files.  This is a personal decision you will have to make we cannot help you make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **no** good reason to keep them. Windows 7 without Sp1 is out of support, so removing Sp1 make so sense any longer. It was valid when Sp1 came in 2011. Here it was a valid option if you run into an issue with the Sp1 which didn't happen in Win7 RTM.